# How to scroll hidden items in to view using Angular & Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, intersection-observer

I have an app that contains a list of horizontally scrolled images. For desktop usability, I would like to add arrows to the left and right side of the screen that a user can click on to programmatically scroll more items on to the screen. I'm trying to replicate something like the following behavior found on Tidal (gif):

https://giphy.com/embed/MDrRdBfFqktZ64CHko

As you can see, when you click the right arrow, it takes the album that is on the right side of the screen and moves it all the way over to the left side, thus displaying more albums. But if there is no more items to scroll, it simply aligns the last item on the right side fully on to the screen.

My first attempt was to create an Intersection Observer directive and add it to all of the list elements to keep track of the visible items. So programmatically I handle that like so:

```
const sources = this.intersectionObservers.map((element) => {
  return element.inViewportAction;
})

combineLatest(sources).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
).subscribe((e) => {
  this.listElements = e.map(({ target, visible }) => ({
    target,
    visible
  }));
  this.visibleElements = this.listElements.filter((el) => {
    return el.visible == true;
  })
})
```

Where `listElements` stores all elements in the horizontal scroll container like this:

[image]

And `visibleElements` is that same array but with only the elements that have `visible: true`.
When you scroll, the directive handles updating which elements are `visible` and updates the `listElements` and `visibleElements` automatically

Now, when the `right` arrow is clicked, it triggers an `onNext()` method that grabs the `target` of the last visible element and programmatically scrolls:

```
scrollNext() {
  // get target (HTML Element) of last viewable element
  var lastViewableEl = this.visibleElements.pop().target;
  // here's where I need to scroll it to the left side of the page
  lastViewableEl.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Obviously `scrollIntoView` doesn't work here because the item already is in view. I can't hard-code a `scrollTo` value because then we wouldn't be accounting for screen width changes. How should I handle something like this using Angular / Javascript? Thanks!

---

FYI, if necessary:

I am using `ng-content` projection to be able to reuse my grid component, so here's the html to display my horizontal grid items:

**horizontal-scroll-grid.component.html**

```
<div class="hs-grid" [class.hs-noPrevious]="noPrevious" [class.hs-noNext]="noNext">
  <button type="button"(click)="scrollNext()">
  </button>
  <button type="button" (click)="scrollPrevious()">
  </button>
  <div class="hs full" detect-scroll (onScroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.page.html**

```
<app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
  <app-album-item inViewport *ngFor="let releaseEl of releases" [submission]="releaseEl"></app-album-item>
</app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
```